# Fans on motherbaord and chassis not spinning after replacing power supply

Tags: power-supply, computer-building, repair

Fans in the motherboard doesn't spin after replacing the psu.
The old one doesn't work so I replace it with a new ones (forgot model name) of 240v.

the small led in the motherboard shines but the cpu and chassis fans are not spinning.

Should I need to replace my motherboard?

The PC is pretty old with intel pentium processor and 2gigs of ram (ddr3 1333 O.C)

Comment: Are the fans plugged in correctly? https://10scopes.com/where-to-plug-in-case-fans/
You can also check SpeedFan https://www.almico.com/speedfan.php

Comment: So everything else works other than the fans? Boots up and displays? Is this true for the CPU fan as well as case fans? I assume you mean 240 watts and not volts too.

Comment: Both the CPU fans and case fans are not spinning! I re-install the fans and still not working!
and it Doesn't boot :(